# How do I get this code to work for sub folders (folders inside the main 'commands' folder)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, discord.js, fs

How do I get this code to work for sub folders (folders inside the main 'commands' folder)? Here is some of my code.

Index.js:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args, client);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        const errembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#009ACD')
        .setDescription('There was an error trying to execute that command!')
        message.channel.send(errembed);
    }   
});
```

Examplecommand.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
      name: 'command name',
      description: 'command description',
      execute(message, args) {
//code here
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to get this to work in sub-folders with an elegant solution, so I think this is what you should do:

```
client.subFolderCommands = new Discord.Collection();

const subFolderFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/subfolder').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (var i = 0; i < subFolderFiles.length; i++) {
    const command = require(`./commands/subfolder/${subFolderFiles[i]}`);
    client.subFolderCommands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

If you know a better solution, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is make the `readdirSync` method return the files and/or directories as [`directory entry (Dirent)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent). You can do this by setting the option `withFileTypes` to `true` in the [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) method. Then you can iterate over the results and if an entry is a subdirectory, read all the files/directories from that folder. You can check this with the [`isDirectory()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dirent_isdirectory) function.

Here's an example that could work:

```js
function readFilesFromPath(pathString) {
    const directoryEntries = fs.readdirSync(pathString, {withFileTypes: true});

    return directoryEntries.reduce((filteredEntries, dirEnt) => {
        if (dirEnt.isDirectory()) {
            // If the entry is a directory, call this function again
            // but now add the directory name to the path string.
            filteredEntries.push(...readFilesFromPath(`${pathString}/${dirEnt.name}`))
        } else if (dirEnt.isFile()) {
            // Check if the entry is a file instead. And if so, check
            // if the file name ends with `.js`.
            if (dirEnt.name.endsWith('.js') {
                // Add the file to the command file array.
                filteredEntries.push(`${pathString}/${dirEnt.name}`);
            }
        }

        return filteredEntries;
    }, []);
}

// Call the read files function with the root folder of the commands and
// store all the file paths in the constant.
const commandFilePaths = readFilesFromPath('./commands');

// Loop over the array of file paths and set the command on the client.
commandFilePaths.forEach((filePath) => {
    const command = require(filePath);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my command handler with subfolder support.
Just replace first 5 lines with these

```js
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');
for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}
```